# How does a loop work on basic computer level?

Tags: python

For instance, In python

```
for i in range(5):
   print(i)
```

This is a basic loop, but inside a computer what goes on processing the loop in general. How does a computer perform a loop?
For us humans we simply write `for` and the loop works, but how does the computer do it?

Comment: Try to learn about computer architecture and assembly language programming.

Comment: The for loop is an element of the Python language. While its behaviour is defined by the language it is no defined how it should be implemented. The implementation is subject of the interpreter and every interpreter has its own. If you want to know sbout implementation details you should check the source code of the interpreter you are interested in.

Answer (score 3):

Python includes [the `dis` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html) for 'disassembling' your code. This gives you a picture of what the bytecode for your function might look like* - the step-by-step instructions the computer performs.

```
>>> def example():
...     for i in range(5):
...         print(i)
... 
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(example)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (range)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 (5)
              4 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              6 GET_ITER
        >>    8 FOR_ITER                12 (to 22)
             10 STORE_FAST               0 (i)

  3          12 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (print)
             14 LOAD_FAST                0 (i)
             16 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             18 POP_TOP
             20 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            8
        >>   22 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             24 RETURN_VALUE
```

Here we can see that the process is roughly:

1. Preload the function `range()`
2. Push the constant `5` to the top of the stack
3. Call the function `range()`
4. Put the resultant iterator at the top of the stack
5. Use the `FOR_ITER` instruction, which seems to function as a "jump if iter is expended" to line 22, and otherwise does nothing
6. Repeatedly tap the iterator, load the `print()` function, call it, and jump back to the beginning of the `for` loop
7. Once the `for` loop ends, load `None` to the top of the stack, and return it (since the function `example()` doesn't explicitly return anything else)

---

*Note that `dis` does not give you the actual machine code the computer runs. Instead, it returns python bytecode:

> Bytecode is an implementation detail of the CPython interpreter.

In other words, your python code is compiled to bytecode, and then the python runtime interprets that bytecode. There's not a perfect one-to-one match between python bytecode instructions and Assembly instructions (especially since those ASM instructions would differ depending on your computer's CPU architecture) but for most purposes it's sufficient to figure out what's going on.

In this case, the idioms are pretty similar. The difference is that in the major ASM varieties you might be more likely to see the parameters to functions `range()` and `print()` loaded into specific CPU registers rather than pushed to the top of the stack. The typical assembly implementation of a `for` loop would use a similar idiom - a conditional jump ("Jump if zero", probably) at the beginning of the `for` loop, and an unconditional jump before the end back to the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Python is a high-level language, so this answer isn't really appropriate because it does a **lot** of extra stuff under the hood.

But at the lowest level the processor has access to memory, where instructions for the processor are saved (e.g. 'add this register to this register' and 'save this register to this memory location'). It also crucially has an *instruction pointer*, which indicates the position in memory of the next instruction it should execute.

A loop is essentially a block of code that at the end sets the instruction pointer back to the start of the loop, unless some condition is met (in your example, when `i >= 5`). It would be the equivalent of this:

1. Do something.
2. Do some more stuff.
3. We're doing stuff!
4. Add 1 to i.
5. Is i equal to 5? Go to instruction 7.
6. Go to step 1.
7. We're out of the loop!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to understand how `for` loop works in terms of `while` loop, then you can refer to this code:

```
sequence = iter(range(5))
try:
    while True:
        i = next(sequence)
        print(i)
except StopIteration:
    pass
```

This is how, I believe, it works. If you want to understand it at much lower level, you should read @Green Cloak Guy's answer.